# Unique string from each row SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has data like this:

```
colA | animals
1    | horse, mouse
2    | dog,cat,dog
3    | cat, rat
4    | rat, rat, bug
```

I want the output to be as shown below where I want to iterate through each row and get only the unique values.

```
colA | animals
1    | horse, mouse
2    | dog,cat
3    | cat, rat
4    | rat, bug
```

I know `distinct` is all the distinct values in a column but do not know how to do it for each row. Is there any command that can do it?

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: I needed it in this format since I am going to run the FPgrowth algorithm. Each row would represent the products bought by a customer.

Comment: @juergend Probably.. but mistakes are part of the learning process. If you can't give a suggestion, you can totally ignore my post instead of being downright rude.

Comment: I gave a suggestion: changing your DB design. And I was not rude. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  colA, 
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT TRIM(animal), ',')
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(animals)) animal
  ) animals
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY colA
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 colA, 'horse, mouse' animals UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'dog,cat,dog' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'cat, rat' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'rat, rat, bug'
)
SELECT 
  colA, 
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT TRIM(animal), ',')
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(animals)) animal
  ) animals
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY colA
```

with output as below

```sql
colA    animals  
1       horse,mouse  
2       dog,cat  
3       cat,rat  
4       rat,bug
```

If you do not need colA in your output  - just do not include it in SELECT

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT TRIM(animal), ',')
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(animals)) animal
  ) animals
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Also in case when colA in not needed - below version will work too

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT TRIM(animal), ',') distinct_animals
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(SPLIT(animals)) animal
GROUP BY animals
```

Comment: Is it possible to not do a hard coding because I have several records?

Comment: see update  - hope you got it now :o) - you should use your reference instead of \`project.dataset.table`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to get rid of my colA and for some reason running into a problem. I tried not including colA and instead use the nested select command. Could you please edit it to include colA? Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: include or not included? clarify please

Comment: Sorry!! Not include colA

Comment: it definitely works with data you provided as an example! if you still have error - it means that example you shown is different from what you have in reality. check it :o) consider voting up if not yet

Comment: Works now! I missed a parenthesis. I already upvoted and accepted the answer.

Comment: great! also see one more option in my answer :o)